# Get certain part of text and update value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i'd like to update some writing format on my app.
Currently what save in database is like this (example)

```
HI this is link [link](Google Web)google.com[/link]
```

I want to update it to plain HTML tag

```
 HI this is link <a href="google.com"> Google Web</a>
```

I want to update the value directly on mysql

Comment: Are all the data format in the field similar?

Comment: yes the strcutres are the same

Comment: I might have a suggestion but it's a combination of many `CONCAT, SUBSTRING, SUBSTRING_INDEX, LOCATE and REPLACE` functions. You can try the `SELECT` query first and see if it return the result how you want it.

Comment: yes, currently i'm playing with all of those, i'll update the answer if i get one

Comment: For your latest question: `allItems = data.data.reduce((acc, o) => { k = Object.keys(o)[0]; acc[k] = o[k]; return acc; })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my current solution

**Step 1.**
Put tag a link inside previous format

```
UPDATE infos
set subject = REPLACE(subject,
substring_index(substring_index(subject, '[link]', -1), '[/link]', 1), 
CONCAT("<a href='"
,substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(subject, '[link]', -1), '[/link]', 1), ')', -1)   
,"'>"
,substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(subject, '[link]', -1), '[/link]', 1), '(', -1), ')', 1)
,"</a>")
)
WHERE subject LIKE '%(%'
AND subject LIKE '%)%'
AND subject LIKE '%[link]%'
AND subject LIKE '%[/link]%'
```

**Step 2**
Delete the [link] and [/link] tag

```
UPDATE infos
set subject = REPLACE(REPLACE(subject, "[link]<a", "<a"), "</a>[/link]", "</a>")
WHERE subject LIKE '%[link]%'
AND subject LIKE '%[/link]%'
```

**Watchout**
If you have multiple link inside 1 subject, it won't directly change it all, you have to redo the step1 and 2 until no rows is affected

Answer (score 1):

If all the data format similar to the example, try with this:

```
SELECT val,
       CONCAT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(val,'[link]','<a href="'),1,LOCATE('(',val)+2),SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(val,LOCATE(')',val)+1,999),'[/',' '),' ',1),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(val,SUBSTRING(val,LOCATE('(',val)),' ">'),' ',-1),SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(val,LOCATE('(',val)+1),')',1),REPLACE(SUBSTRING(val,LOCATE('/',val)-1),SUBSTRING(val,LOCATE('/',val)-1),'</a>')) newVal
       FROM yourTable;
```

Here's a quick example in fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2kCoc6DbDLh8gHPJ9Yawk9/0

Comment: Good try. But if you have something like this instead: `HI this )is link` it's not working. I was thinking also for some solution using `REPLACE` and without custom regex functionality, but cannot find anything simple. But this approach is more complicated approach, so probably you can fix it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I am currently trying with all the possibilities. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll try and fix that xD